# Codeigniter redirect does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I use Codeigniter and I would like to create a redirecting function, my code:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect('/main');
```

This is redirecting me to `http://localhost/Main.php/main` but I would like to be redirected to `http://localhost/main/`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: URL helper is a common helper that you most likely would need all over. I would auto load it in `application > config > autoload.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
redirect(base_url('main'));
```

Comment: Thank you! The function is working properly with this.